# How to use switch-case on a Type?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a better alternative than this to 'switch on type'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298976/c-sharp-is-there-a-better-alternative-than-this-to-switch-on-type)

I need to iterate through all properties of my class and to check if its type of int the i need to do something, if its string .. then do something. I need it using switch-case. Here i am using switch in the following manner, but it asks for some constant. see the code below:

```
 public static bool ValidateProperties(object o)
{
    if(o !=null)
    {
        var sourceType = o.GetType();
        var properties = sourceType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var type = property.GetType();
            switch (type)
            {
                *case typeof(int):* getting error here
                    // d
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also i want to know , what check should I use, typeof(int) or typeof(Int32)?

Comment: FYI, both questions are of different context. He is asking on controls , while i am asking on data types. Please be sure before any down voting or close voting. Don't be blind. Guys having such reputations are not supposed to do such kiddish mistakes.

Comment: see also
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156467/switch-pattern-matching-idea
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252186/switch-case-on-type-c-sharp
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478464/c-sharp-switch-on-type
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298976/c-sharp-is-there-a-better-alternative-than-this-to-switch-on-type

Comment: and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94305/what-is-quicker-switch-on-string-or-elseif-on-type
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149788/c-sharp-switch-on-object-type-at-runtime
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304815/why-is-this-switch-on-type-case-considered-confusing
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947343/how-to-switch-between-possible-type-of-an-object
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115028/best-way-to-switch-behavior-based-on-type
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551773/c-sharp-which-is-the-best-alternative-to-switch-on-type

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You cannot use a switch block to test values of type `Type`. Compiling your code should give you an error saying something like:

> A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string,
>   integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type

You'll need to use `if`-`else` statements instead.

Also: `typeof(int)` and `typeof(Int32)` are equivalent. `int` is a keyword and `Int32` is the type name.

**UPDATE**

If you expect that most types will be intrinsic you may improve performance by using a switch block with `Type.GetTypeCode(...)`.

For example:

```
switch (Type.GetTypeCode(type))
{
    case TypeCode.Int32:
        // It's an int
        break;

    case TypeCode.String:
        // It's a string
        break;

    // Other type code cases here...

    default:
        // Fallback to using if-else statements...
        if (type == typeof(MyCoolType))
        {
            // ...
        }
        else if (type == typeof(MyOtherType))
        {
            // ...
        } // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 11):

A good and extensible way to do this is to make a dictionary of types and delegates of appropriate type, based on what you want to do with values of that type.

For example:

```
var typeProcessorMap = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>
{
    { typeof(int), new Action<int>(i => { /* do something with i */ }) },
    { typeof(string), new Action<string>(s => { /* do something with s */ }) },
};
```

And then:

```
void ValidateProperties(object o)
{
    var t = o.GetType();
    typeProcessorMap[t].DynamicInvoke(o); // invoke appropriate delegate
}
```

This solution is extensible, configurable even at run time, and as long as you keep the keys and types of delegate values in `typeProcessorMap` correctly matched is also type safe.

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/7ecHO)**.

Comment: This is a nice solution, bearing in mind that `DynamicInvoke` can be a bit slow in performance-critical sections.

Comment: @KirkWoll: Would making all of the delegates `Action<object>` and casting the parameter inside the delegate body be faster? I 'm not sure exactly what `DynamicInvoke` does behind the scenes.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what `DynamicInvoke` does behind the scenes either. :)  But I posted an "answer" below to illustrate the performance difference.

Comment: Apparently has/had Skeet's blessing [in 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/a/298994/1028230). Fwiw, however, the ideone link isn't working for me (OS X & Safari).

Answer (score 5):

Usually, the easiest solution is to switch on the type name:

```
switch (type.Name)
{
    case "Int32":
    ...
}
```

Comment: IMO, the sacrifice of type-safety is not worth it.  After all, an if/else chain is almost equally concise and has the virtue of catching typos (and far more importantly -- future refactorings) at compile-time.

Comment: Have you guys heard about unit tests? Anyway, I do use Jon's approach sometimes, but it's usually overkill.

Comment: @Diego, unit tests **are not** a replacement for type safety.

Answer (score 5):

*This "answer" is an elaboration for Jon's answer.  (Marking CW)*

For the record, `DynamicInvoke` is a bit slow.  To illustrate this, consider the following program:

```
void Main()
{
    Func<int, string> myFunc = i => i.ToString();
    myFunc.DynamicInvoke(1);   // Invoke once so initial run costs are not considered
    myFunc(1);

    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    stopwatch.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        myFunc.DynamicInvoke(1);
    stopwatch.Stop();

    var elapsed = stopwatch.Elapsed;

    stopwatch.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        myFunc(1);
    stopwatch.Stop();

    var elapsed2 = stopwatch.Elapsed;

    Console.WriteLine("DynamicInvoke: " + elapsed);
    Console.WriteLine("Direct Invocation: " + elapsed2);
}
```

Prints out:

> DynamicInvoke: 00:00:03.1959900
>   Direct Invocation: 00:00:00.0735220

Which means that `DynamicInvoke` (in this simple case) is 42 times slower than direct invocation.