# Unity Convert SerializedProperty To Generic

Tags: unity-game-engine, converters

I'm trying to make a function that gets a SerializedProperty via a string path and then it converts it into a generic type and returns that. I have tried many solutions and they either gives an exception of null refrence or invalid cast. I simply have no clue on what to do. So could someone be kind and help me? thanks!
btw this is the function so far:

```
T GetObjectProperty<T>(string propertyPath)
{
    SerializedProperty property = serializedObject.FindProperty(propertyPath);



}
```

Comment: In your example you are not returning anything. What exactly do you want to do? / What is your goal with that?

Comment: The goal of this function is to first find the property via the propertyPath (there is no otherway to do this part) and then get the T value from the property and return that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that simple unfortunately: [Unity - SerializedProperty](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedProperty.html) has a lot of different properties like e.g. `intValue`, `floatValue`, `boolValue`.

If you are after an object reference as the naming of your function sounds to me you are probably after the `objectReferenceValue`.

---

Otherwise you somehow have to define exactly which value you want to access; I did this once by passing the wanted type as second parameter:

```c#
object GetValueByName(Type type, string name)
{
    SerializedProperty property = serializedObject.FindProperty(name);

    if(type == typeof(int))
    {
        return property.intValue;
    } 
    else if(type == typeof(float))
    {
        return property.floatValue;
    }
    //... and so on

}
```

Than whenever I used the method I only had to parse like e.g.

```c#
int someValue = (int)GetValueByName(typeof(int), "XY");
```

---

If you want to stick to the genric method instead of returning `object` and parse you can as well check for `typeof(T)` instead of pssing it as parameter:

```c#
T GetValueByName<T>(string name)
{
    SerializedProperty property = serializedObject.FindProperty(name);

    Type type = typeof(T);
    if(type == typeof(int))
    {
        return property.intValue;
    } 
    else if(type == typeof(float))
    {
        return property.floatValue;
    }
    //... and so on

}
```

hope this helps you

---

(ps: if you prefere to use `switch`-`case` instead of the multiple `if`-`else` refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7542810/7111561))